# Spacy SpanGroup

Tags: python, spacy

I am trying to use spaCy's SpanGroup class, but the following commands both give a ModuleNotFoundError:

`from spacy.tokens.span_group import SpanGroup` and
`from spacy.tokens import SpanGroup`

I tried looking at the spaCy documentation, but their command wasn't working. Does someone know the correct command to import SpanGroup?

Comment: What version of spaCy is installed in your environment? SpanGroup was introduced in spaCy v3 so if you are using anything lower you probably won't have it.

Comment: I am using spacy==3.1

Answer (score 1):

The code in [the docs](https://spacy.io/api/spangroup#_title) works for me.

```
from spacy.tokens import SpanGroup
```

Does that give you an error?